# yacc - rules never reduced and shift/reduce conflicts

Tags: compiler-construction

I have faced a problem dealing with yaac, since I keep getting this note:

1 rule never reduced.
29 shift/reduce conflicts.

So, could anyone help me please to fix this problem?

This is the grammar that I am working on:

```
%start P
%token DEF IF THEN ELSE WHILE DO FOR
%token Punctuation_element
%token Operator
%token EQL_EQL GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS NOT_EQUALS 
%token<sval> Identifier
%token<ival> Literal

%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%right ELSE

%%

P :   D ';' P 
|     D
;

D :  DEF Identifier '(' ARGS ')' '=' E ';'
;

ARGS: Identifier ',' ARGS 
|     Identifier
;

E:    Literal
|     Identifier
|     IF E OP E THEN E ELSE E 
|     FOR E DO E
|     DO E WHILE E
|     E '+' E 
|     E '-' E
|     E '*' E
|     E '/' E
|     E '%' E
|     Identifier '(' E ')'
|     E ',' E
;

/* C:   E ',' C 
|   E  
; */

OP:   EQL_EQL 
|     '>' 
|     '<' 
|     GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS 
|     LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS 
|     NOT_EQUALS 
|     '%'
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two fundamental problems:

1. `%` is both a comparison operator (`OP`) and an arithmetic operator (`E '%' E`). That creates an ambiguity which bison resolves in favour of the arithmetic operator, because bison favours shift over reduce. That resolution makes it impossible to reduce `OP : '%'`, which is the rule not reduced.
2. You make `,` an arithmetic operator (`E ',' E`) but you don't declare a precedence for it. That leads to a lot of shift reduce conflicts for expressions involving `,` and another operator. I doubt that you actually want `,` to be an operator at all; I think you added the production involving it in order to allow function calls with multiple arguments. That's not going to work. Create a separate non-terminal for argument lists and use it in the production for function calls instead of using `E`.

   (In fact, you have such a non-terminal, mysteriously called `C`, but it's commented out and unused. So uncomment it and use it. And consider giving it a more meaningful name.)

LALR parser generators like bison generally prefer left recursion to right recursion. You should consider changing both of your list productions (`C` and `ARGS`) to left recursion, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to fix the rule that never reduced.

non-terminal C has been created to avoid the problem of ( E, E ), so, it's the solution that are you trying to refer to?

One last question: do the shift/reduce conflicts would make the parser not working for some cases? like the rule that never reduced.

Comment: @faisal: I don't know how to fix your productions fir `%` because I don't know what language you are trying to implement. All I can tell  you is that what you have won't work because you can't use the same symbol for two operators with different precedences.

Comment: This is the grammar that I'm trying to solve:
`P-> D ; P | D 
        D -> def id(ARGS) = E;
        ARGS -> id , ARGS | id
        E -> int | id| if E1 OP E2 then E3 else E4 | for E1 do E2 |do E1 while E2
 | E1+E2 | E1-E2 |E1*E2|E1/E2|E1%E2 | id(E1, …, En)
       OP -> == | > | < | >= | <= | != |%`

I want to use % as OP and inside E.

Comment: @Faisal: you can't, it's ambiguous. And repeating your grammar in a comment doesn't provide any additional information. Consider the expression `if a % b % c then 0 else 1`. Which of those percents is the `OP` and which is the arithmetic operator? Your grammar doesn't provide any hint.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. But, how can I rewrite the grammar to eliminate this ambiguity with also remaining the same concept?

Comment: @Faisal: I don't know. Tell me the answer to my question: How do you decide which % means what? If you can't answer that question, you can't write a grammar. And I have no idea what you have in mind.

Comment: Finally, I have solved the problem of the rule that never reduced, by having a new non-terminal (`OPM`) that have the production `%`. And then create also a new production for  `E` which is      `IF E OPM E THEN E ELSE E` and remove the (`%`) from (`OP`), and change one of the productions of E with    `E OPM E`    instead of (`%`).


One Question please: Do the shift/reduce conflicts in the grammar may produce wrong results? or an error? in some case

Comment: @faisal: that change does remove one error message but it doesn't change anything else. Your grammar is still ambiguous; you still have conflicts; and that means some expressions will be parsed incorrectly. You **must** fix the ambiguity, and that means you must figure out the meaning of expressions like the one in my comment.